# xquery запрос mssql

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery

Для теста работы с xml структурами в бд создал таблицу, в которой единственный столбец формата `XMLTYPE`.

Успешно подкрутил схемы к бд.

Первый:

```
<abandonedReasonCode>value1</abandonedReasonCode>
<comissionRoleCodeType>value2</comissionRoleCodeType>
```

Второй:

```
<export xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/export/1" xmlns:oos="http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/types/1">
<contract schemeVersion="1.0">
  <oos:id>13412094</oos:id>
  <oos:regNum>0145100000214000004</oos:regNum>
  <oos:number>75524</oos:number>
  <oos:publishDate>2014-01-10T10:07:59Z</oos:publishDate>
  <oos:signDate>2013-12-31</oos:signDate>
  <oos:versionNumber>0</oos:versionNumber>
</contract>
```

Дальше, собственно, начинаю формировать запросы к записям.

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/types/1' AS oos) 
     SELECT fst.value('(/abandonedReasonCode[1])', 'NVARCHAR(30)') AS 'id'
     FROM Table_1;
```

Данный запрос работает и выводит значение `value1` из первой записи. И `NULL` из второй.

Но вот следующий запрос выдает `NULL` в обоих записях, хоть во второй записи есть значение, отличное от пустого.

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/types/1' AS oos) 
SELECT fst.value('(/contract[1]/oos:id[1])', 'integer') AS 'oos:id' FROM 
Table_1;
```

Вот и хочется узнать, почему это не работает

Comment: mssql или mysql? В заголовке одно, в теге - другое.

Comment: Просвятите, пожалуйста. Я думал, что mssql это лишь расширенный mysql. Но работаю в среде mssql - это точно) В чем разница синтакса в моем примере?

Comment: Давайте с самого начала: как называется СУБД, которую вы используете - MySQL или SqlServer?

Comment: MicrosoftSqlServer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во втором xml имеется пространство имен по умолчанию. Его тоже нужно указывать при запросе.

Этот запрос вернет значение из второго xml:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/types/1' AS oos,
                   'http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/export/1' AS def)
SELECT fst.value('(def:export[1]/def:contract[1]/oos:id[1])', 'integer') AS 'oos:id'
FROM Table_1;
```

Неймспейс по умолчанию можно задать и так:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/types/1' AS oos,
                   DEFAULT 'http://zakupki.gov.ru/oos/export/1')
SELECT fst.value('(export[1]/contract[1]/oos:id[1])', 'integer') AS 'oos:id'
FROM Table_1;
```